# Inserting users into webpages_Membership with known passwords

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I need to import a bunch of data (user accounts among it) into my new MVC4 apps. The passwords are currently stored in plain text. I'd like be able to migrate all the accounts without asking the users to reset their password. Is it possible to do in SQL alone, or do I have to rely on code and call `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` for every user?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use CreateUserAndAccount because SimpleMembership expects the passwords to be hashed.  Unless you know the hashing algorithm and can implement it in SQL I do not see any other way.